# How to print only git message/title using bash script?

Tags: git

I can print the current git commit `sha1` in bash using this command:

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

But how can I print only the latest commit message/title of the HEAD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I quite like

```
git show --oneline -s HEAD
```

If you only want to see the message, use

```
git show --pretty=format:%s -s HEAD
```

instead. To add the SHA-1:

```
git show --pretty=format:"%H %s" -s HEAD
```

(or `%h` for the abbreviated SHA-1).

See [the `git show` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#_pretty_formats) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Another option can be to use `git log`

To get the commit title

```bash
git log -1 --pretty=%s
```

To get commit whole body

```bash
git log -1 --pretty=%B
```

To get commit hash

```bash
git log -1 --pretty=%H
```

To get commit `--short` hash

```bash
git log -1 --pretty=%s
```

To get commit short hash and title

```bash
git log -1 --pretty="%h: %s"
```